# LaTeX font package on stackexchange

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I'm wondering what math fonts are used by stackexchange, and how I can use them in my own LaTeX environment.

For instance, the following code does give me the times new roman font for texts, but it does not give me the desired math fonts.

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

Is there a way to use these fonts in my own LaTeX environment? It would be better if the package is compatible with the software Texpad, since I use it to edit my LaTeX files.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What do you mean with "don't quite work"? Does the font not change? Do you not like those fonts (they are Times New Roman variants)? What do you mean with "math fonts used by stackexchange"?

Comment: [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/484424/106162) might be what you want?

Comment: note stackexchange does not use tex it is using mathjax so it is not using any latex font pakage.

Comment: @Marijn I just edited the question. What I want is literally the math fonts used by the stackexchange. For instance, if I use newtxmath, then the symbol \mathcal{O} looks strange and I prefer the way it looks on stackexchange. Hope that clarifies things a bit.

Comment: Maybe only `\usepackage{newtxtext}` (without the other two packages) would be what you want? This would change only the text font to a Times variant while leaving the math font to the LaTeX default, which is close to the MathJax font (i.e., the font that Stack Exchange uses on the sites where math is enabled).